# Word Automation Service won't start on specific site collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, word-automation

I have a SharePoint (2010, Standard edition) farm with three site collections. 
On each site collection is a Word Automation service associated.

Let's assume each sitecollection listen on different ports:

- 80
- 90
- 100

When I try to convert a Word document to PDF with the Word Automation Service via PowerShell it will succeed on port 80, also on port 90.

But not on port 100.

So I checked the permissions for the service and the database. Both are set to the application pool identity.

I didn't get any error in the ULS that helps me out to figure out the problem.
Does anyone have an idea that can explain the problem?

Comment: Can you use `Set-SPLogLevel -TraceSeverity VerboseEx`, then repeat and see if you can find any errors with WAS? Use `Clear-SPLogLevel` once you've completed your test.

Comment: do you have all site collections in one web app or 3 different web apps? what error you get in powershell window?

Comment: I have all sitecollections in three different webapplications. I got only the error that the conversion is failed in the job Queue (Errorcpunt is set to one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved the problem.
The Issue was, that there existst three databases that couldn't be upgraded.

Because in the log I got sometimes upgrade error messaged.

The database that couldn't be upgraded, wasn't used by any Serives and are obsolete. So I deleted them and after this it works perfect.

I wondered why this can accour a problem with the word automation service.